# Extjs - upload multi type file

Tags: extjs, file-upload, upload, extjs4.1

I have tbar with filefield like this

```
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        name: 'myforms',
        border: false,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'filefield',
            name: 'myname[]',
            buttonText:'add'
        }]
    }]
```

I try to upload zip file, mp4 file,... but not working. it's working with simple type example: txt, doc,...

 my submit using

```
form.submit({
    method: 'POST',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    ....
});
```

How can i fix that thanks

**Edit**

I try more and i see if file > about 2M, it will not upload. :( I don't catch any size of file more 2M. How can i upload more 2M thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's limitation on your server side. I know that IIS for example has configuration option allowing you to change that default size - that is if you're using IIS + WCF or something similar.

What's your server back end?

Comment: Now i test it on local using xampp

Comment: Still. Check xamppp config: http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/File_upload_size#XAMPP_on_Mac_Instructions

Answer (score 0):

> > You can do like this :
> >
> > ```
> > uploadFile: function(request) {
> >     var file = request.file;
> >         data = new FormData();
> >     data.append('file', file);
> >     Ext.Ajax.request({
> >         url: url ,
> >         scope: this,
> >         rawData: data,
> >         headers: {'Content-Type':null},
> >         success: function(response) {
> >            var responseData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText, true);
> >         }
> >     });
> > }
> > ```
> >
> > and inside your application.properties in spring boot:
> >
> > spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
> >     spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB if you are using spring boot.

Comment: Could you explain how this fixes the problem occurring for files larger than 2 MB?

Comment: oh yes forget to mention put this inside your application.properties

spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer! You don't need to comment as well.